# Setting a changing prop value to a child state variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let's assume we have a two components (Parent and Child), basically I am sending my Parents state variable to my child's input element to do some manipulation. Something like...

```
 var Parent = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      name: ''
    }
  },
  handleTextChange: function(e) {
    this.setState({
      name: e.target.value
    })
  },
  render: function() {
    return(
      <div>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter something" onChange={this.handleTextChange} />
      <Child name={this.state.name} />
      </div>
    )
  }
});
```

And my child component looks like this..

```
var Child = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      childName: ''
    }
  },
  componentWillReceiveProps: function(nextProps) {
    this.setState({
      childName: nextProps.name
    })
  },
  handleChildTextChange: function(e) {
    this.setState({
      childName: e.target.value
    })
  },
  render: function() {
    return(
      <div>
        <input type="text" onChange={this.handleChildTextChange} placeholder={this.props.name} />
        <h4>{this.state.childName}</h4>
      </div>
    )
  }
});
```

Basically I want to do 3 things

1. My Child component's childName value should be set initially to that
   of parent's prop(this.props.name which is Parent's state variable
   `name`)
2. On change of my `Child`'s input, the target text should override my
   Parent's name(this.props.name)
3. If my child input is empty and my `Parent`'s name is changing, I
   want my `Child`'s component state variable `childName` to be that of
   the changing prop coming from the parent(this.props.name)

Can anybody please help me with this?

P.S : My `Child`'s components target text shouldn't update my `Parent`'s state variable(name) I mean, no Callbacks as props.

Comment: As you are passing it as a prop, why force it to be inside state? Just pass it as a prop, and pass a handler for when the value changes

Comment: I'm adding it to a state variable because on change of my child input I want the changed value to be assigned to a state variable. Also, I need the this.props.name only on the initial render of my child component.

Comment: The three points helped, why not set an extra state value to indicate that the child "owns" the current name, and not the parent? I updated the answer slightly

Answer (score 0):

I think you should only set the state to your this.props.name when getting the initial state value, and not on each componentWillReceiveProps sample. Once the child sets it's own state, the value will only change in the child and not in the parent

```js
var Child = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      childName: this.props.name,
      owned: false
    }
  },
  componentWillReceiveProps: function(nextProps) {
    // only do it if the state isn't owned by the child
    if (!this.state.owned) {
      this.setState({
        childName: nextProps.name,
        owned: false
      });
    }
  },
  handleChildTextChange: function(e) {
    this.setState({
      childName: e.target.value,
      owned: true
    });
  },
  render: function() {
    return(
      <div>
        <input type="text" onChange={this.handleChildTextChange} placeholder={this.props.name} />
        <h4>{this.state.childName}</h4>
      </div>
    )
  }
});

var Parent = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      name: ''
    }
  },
  handleTextChange: function(e) {
    this.setState({
      name: e.target.value
    })
  },
  render: function() {
    return(
      <div>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter something" onChange={this.handleTextChange} />
      <Child name={this.state.name} />
      </div>
    )
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
</div>
```